# Modify query from RDBMS to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

**select col1, col2 from table1 where col1 > 10**

What will be query in MongoDB ?

Comment: There is this awesome thing called Google, you should try using it

Comment: This is covered well in their docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be like :

```
db.table1.find({col1:{$gt:10}},{col1:1,col2:1})
```

For more information read this document : [db.collection.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Comment: I would downvote this tbh since it encourages questions like this...

Comment: You can downvote to the question & vote for the close if you want to discourage this kind of questions. I am just trying to help people by answering.